# c# declaring a variable as a parameter, novice question

Tags: c#

I've been working a week on teaching myself C# (with no C++ or Java), on a project of making an elaborate poker-hand parser. I'm finally caving in and posting my first simple question.

I think I've seen variable declarations in various ways (new to my VB/A experience). Here's the general idea of what I'd like to do.

```
public class CompareHandsClass : IComparer<clHiHand>
```

...

```
public class clCardsHeld
{   
    protected List<clCard> _liCards = new List<clCard>();

    public clCardsHeld(List<clCard> CardsList)
    {   _liCards = CardsList;
    }
```

...

```
public class clHiHand : clCardsHeld
{
    public clHiHand(List<clCard> CardsList) : base(CardsList) {}

    List<clCard> _liTempCards;
    CompareHandsClass HandComparer = new CompareHandsClass(); 
    ...
    if (_liTempCards.Count >= 5 
    && HandComparer.Compare(clHiHand x = new clHiHand(_liTempCards), 
                            clHiHand y = new clHiHand(_liFlushCards)))
```

So my problem is down at the end with HandComparer.Compare. I've got two Lists of my clCard type, but I can't send them to .Compare() because that takes clHiHand objects. So I'm trying to send the lists as arguments to constructors of temporary clHiHand type variables all at once. I can do this somehow can't I (aside from using several lines of declarations)? Thanks for any beginner's help (I'm kind of disappointed I get stumped on this little thing of all places...)

Oh and, PS, I hope I didn't mess up anything else in this sample code, since I've gotten away from my last working version with these extensions.

Comment: So are you saying that you have a clHiHand comparer and you want to use it to compare clCard types? Unless your clCard type is a subclass of clHiHand then you cannot do this. It's like using a string comparer to compare ints. There has to be a relationship between clCard and clHiHand.

Comment: You can cast the _liTempCards and _LiFlushCards to clHiHand as Ken suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lose the `clHiHand x` and `clHiHand y`. The call then looks like

```
HandComparer.Compare(new clHiHand(_liTempCards), new clHiHand(_liFlushCards))
```